# Why don't backslashes work when using os.path.exists() in python but forward slashes do work?

Tags: python, os.path

I am learning how to use the OS module in python and when i copy the file path from the file explorer directly into python like follows:

```
os.path.exists('C:\Users\nheme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\Flowmeter 
Lab\example.docx')
Out[43]: False
```

The output is False, which doesn't make sense because the file and path definitely do exist. Then when i replace the backslashes with forward slashes as follows:

```
os.path.exists('C://Users//nheme//Documents//Classes//ME 4720 TSL//Flowmeter 
Lab/example.docx')
Out[42]: True
```

It returns True. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: It does make sense : `'\n'` is a newline, which isn't present in your path. `'\\n'` is a backslash followed by an `n`. `'/n'` is converted `'\\n'`.

Comment: This is because the backslash is an escape character.

Comment: try putting an 'r' in front of the path. `(r'C:\Users\nheme\Documents)`

Comment: I think its returning true because the OS module has some formatting already built in which is accounting for the double forward slash

Answer (score 1):

Because backslash is an escape character in Python strings.

Here's what happens when you just try to print that string in Python 2

```
>>> s = 'C:\Users\nheme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\FlowmeterLab\example.docx'
>>> print s
C:\Users
heme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\FlowmeterLab\example.docx
>>>
```

Python has interpreted the `\n` as the escape code for a newline.

There are ways around that, eg, using a raw string

```
>>> s = r'C:\Users\nheme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\FlowmeterLab\example.docx'
>>> print s
C:\Users\nheme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\FlowmeterLab\example.docx
>>>
```

or you could change all the `\` to `\\`

```
>>> s = 'C:\\Users\\nheme\\Documents\\Classes\\ME 4720 TSL\\FlowmeterLab\\example.docx'
>>> print s
C:\Users\nheme\Documents\Classes\ME 4720 TSL\FlowmeterLab\example.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use single backslashes in paths it doesn't work. use `C:\\Users\\nheme\\Documents\\Classes\\ME 4720 TSL\\FlowmeterLab\\example.docx` instead.